# ClientContext - how to tell if you have an active connection?

Tags: client-object-model

I have this code :

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(this.siteURL);
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("AList");
```

I cant seem to access any properties for oList, is there a way to tell that the clientContext object is connected to sharepoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done clientContext.Load(oList) ?

Comment: No, do I need to do that?

Comment: yep, you need to initialize the context with whatever objects you want to have instantiated when you run ExecuteQuery/Async.

Comment: To be fair Microsoft have tried to document this on MSDN. I still think the objects should have more closely resembled stuff like ado.net, but I think once I get more into clientContext it will start making sense! thanks again.